# Jquery Sparkle effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a sparkle effect in jquery but the sparkle is working on background is there anyway i can get those sparkle on image and not on background.

Here is my code:

```js
(function () {
    var sparkle = new Sparkle();
    sparkle.init('.summs');
})();
```

```css
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
  body{margin:0}
  article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}
  a{background:transparent}
  a:active,a:hover{outline:0}
  h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}
  img{border:0}
  svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
  code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace, monospace;font-size:1em}
  b,strong,optgroup{font-weight:700}
  pre,textarea{overflow:auto}

  html {
   height: 100%;
  }

  body {
   color: #AAA;
   background-color: #000;
   line-height: 1.4;
   margin: 50px;
  }

  h1 {
   color: #FFF;
  }

  h2 {
   padding: 10px 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  }

  a {
   color: inherit;
  }

  em {
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-style: normal;
   background-color: #333;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 3px 5px;
  }

  pre {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #444;
   padding: 0 25px;
   border-radius: 3px;
  }

  #wrapper {
   width: 20%;
   margin: auto;
   border:red solid 1px
  }
  div.summs {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://custom.cvent.com/9BC2D0988F874B5C8C15E9D14B6E2F3B/pix/21abaeaeb5d94c73b6814e90cf55d240.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
  height: 516px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: -40px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/creative-event/sparkle-effect/sparkle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summs">
    <div class="onslide2">
        <h1 class="bold"><strong>Sparkling Beauty&nbsp;Sparkling Service</strong></h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1 class="l2">GALA DINNER<br>
            Sparkling Dior Ambassadress</h1>
        <h1 class="l3">26<sup>th</sup> May 2016<br>
            JW Marriott Hotel, Macau</h1>
        <h1 class="l4">Dress Code: Rose Gold and Champagne&nbsp;</h1>
        <h2>Remember to bring your sparkling outfit.<br>
            There will be a prize for best-dressed.</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mL6uf3xm/#)

I am sorry I don't know how make it a link here. Request you to please copy the url and paste.

need help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 2):

I created this myself. Would be nice if you gave me credits somewhere if you use this. But hey, you do what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/mL6uf3xm/5/

Only thing you need to change is

```
mySparkle.init( $( ".summs" ) , 150 );
```

I guess you'll want to keep the element here, but you can change '150' with any number of stars you want.

Have fun

Comment: Cleaner fiddle for those who just want to try it out : https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/mL6uf3xm/6/

Comment: Great contribution!  Thanks.